# JS won't appear in browser with HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am a brand new novice web developer and feel silly cuz I have spent so long trying to figure out why the JS won't show up in my browser with the HTML which shows up as expected.

I wrote a quick `getDate()` JS file that displays perfectly but has no HTML with it. Then I wrote a quick rotate string js file that I placed within the `<script>` tags but only the HTML showed up (a text box).

I tried a different super simple add numbers file (see below) that again only appears as the html heading 'Add Numbers'. I have tried using different browsers and different IDEs and tried putting the js as an external file and directly in the HTML in `<script>` tags  right before the final `</body>`.

I finally copy and pasted a file from MDN tutorials that I know isn't buggy and again no JS just HTML. I am going to be a really bad web developer if I can't figure out how to run my JS and HTML together seamlessly.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Add Numbers</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Add Numbers</h3>

<p>Two plus four equals:</p>

<p id="result"></p>

<script>
function myAddFunc() {
    var a = 2;
    var b = 4;
var result = a + b;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you "call" the function? Add `myAddFunc()` as the last line in your script tag (below `}`)

Comment: Or just remove the function wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Function needs to be invoked (`func()`)  in order for it to run. Alternatively you could remove the function wrapper all together and just have:

```
  var a = 2;
  var b = 4;
  var result = a + b;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
```

In your script tag.

```js
function myAddFunc() {
  var a = 2;
  var b = 4;
  var result = a + b;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
myAddFunc();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Add Numbers</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Add Numbers</h3>

<p>Two plus four equals:</p>

<p id="result"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the issue my not calling the function. It's things like this that ensure I will never forget that again. I feel a little silly for spending so long on such a simple problem but I learn each time so it's worth it. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem! If you could mark the answer as accepted for future viewers that would be great!